# How to make systemd to stop kicking the hardware watchdog

Tags: systemd, watchdog

I have configured systemd to use hardware watchdog. My kernel version is 5.10
This is the configuration

```
RuntimeWatchdogSec=120 in /etc/systemd/system.conf
WatchdogDevice=/dev/watchdog1
```

I can see that the systemd is kicking the hw watchdog and the system is running fine.
I need to test if this hw watchdog indeed resets the hardware so I need to make systemd stop kicking it at run time.
Is this possible ?

I am not able to kill the systemd process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach a debugger to the systemd process. This will pause it until you detach.

```
# gdb -p 1
```